# create command to write with filecontents

Tags: external-files, filecontents, write-file

What's the most efficient way to do this?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week07.tex}
% Week 7
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week08.tex}
% Week 8
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week09.tex}
% Week 9
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week10.tex}
% Week 10
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week11.tex}
% Week 11
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage{filecontents} %% write empty weeklyXX.tex

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\writeweek}[1]{%
\begin{filecontents*}{./weekly/week#1.tex}
% Week #1
\section{}


\end{filecontents*}
}


\writeweek{12}
\writeweek{13}
\writeweek{14}
\writeweek{15}

\end{document}
```

I got some error ...

```
LaTeX Warning: Writing file `././weekly/week12.tex'.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.18 \writeweek{12}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see updated **MWE**. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filecontents` is line `verbatim` and can't be used in the argument to another command, or in a definition, as (in this case) the `%` and `\section` have already been read with their normal meanings before `filecontents` has a chance to write them verbatim.

However you can drop down to lower level code here, and use `\detokenize` to get a kind of verbatim processing

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}  

\newwrite\wks

\begin{document}

{
\catcode`\|=\catcode`\%
\catcode`\%=12 |
\endlinechar=`\^^J |
\gdef\writeweek#1{|
\immediate\openout\wks=./weekly/week#1.tex\relax |
\immediate\write\wks{|
\detokenize{
% Week #1
\section{}

}}|
\immediate\closeout\wks |
}}

\writeweek{12}
\writeweek{13}
\writeweek{14}
\writeweek{15}

\end{document}
```

This makes files that look like

```
% Week 13
\section {}
```